# Is a mapping $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, with harmonic components and positive Jacobian, injective?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $F = \left( \begin{array}{c}
f \\
g
\end{array} \right) \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a mapping, each of its two components are harmonic functions in the plane, i.e. $\Delta(f) \equiv \Delta(g) \equiv 0$.

Suppose the determinant of the Jacobian matrix is positive for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$, and moreover, $\exists \varepsilon$ such that $\det (JF) > \varepsilon$. Does that imply $F$ is injective ?

**Motivation:** For an entire function $h\colon\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, the assumption $h'(z)>\varepsilon$ for all $z$ implies (by Liouville) that $h'(z)=a$ a constant, and thus $h(z)=az+b$ which is a holomorphic automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$. In the question above, $f$ and $g$ are harmonic, but not necessarily conjugate-harmonic. Does injectivity still follow ?

Comment: If you do not require the part with $\varepsilon$, this is false as $f(x,y)=(e^x \cos(y), e^x \sin(y))$ shows. The complex counterpart would still remain true if we only require $f'(z)>0$ (even $f'(z)\in \Bbb{R}$) for all $z$.